# Once when I pressed F5, I got the WCF Test Client

Tags: c#, wcf

..but I haven't seen it yet!  How did I get it?

**Update**
The project is a WCF project.  When F5 is pressed in most circumstances, you simply see a webpage for the entire project (showing that it is running in the background).  However, per the solution below, if your mouse has a .svc file highlighted before you press F5, it will launch the very slick WCF test client - saving you from having to build your own.

[image]

Comment: Is the startup project a WCF project ? How is the startup options set ? Your question is a little vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't remember how to get it run when you hit F5, but you can go to:

Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common/IDE/WcfTestClient.exe

Edit:
Aha! I also found how to get it to run when you hit F5. Right click on any .svc (or .xamlx I think) file and click "Set As Start Page" and whenever you run the Host project, the WCF Test Client should also run.

Comment: BTW, the highlight on the .svc better be blue and the focus on the solution tree.  If it is gray, it won't work either.